# ORDER BY, set a specific case to the first index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008...

I'm having some troubles in trying to order my rows in a specific order that I would like them to be ordered by. I've found a few examples that use the `ORDER BY CASE` clause, but am unsure whether using this method will produce the result that I want it to, thus I come to the community!

Here's what I have:

First, I select, if it exists, a distinct year that is equal to the current year:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT [Year]
FROM Assessment WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectCode AND [Year] = DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()))

SELECT DISTINCT [Year]
FROM Assessment WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectCode
```

But, then I find some confusion in ordering the results. I'd like to set the current year to the first row returned using the `ORDER BY` clause, then order the rest of the returned years in a descending order, here's what I have so far:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Year] = (DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE())) THEN 1
          ELSE 100 END) ASC, [Year] desc
```

Next, if the current year is not contained in the query, select each year and order by year descending.

```
    ELSE
SELECT DISTINCT [Year]
FROM Assessment WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectCode
ORDER BY [Year] desc
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: What is it that is (or is not) happening that should not (or should) be happening?

Comment: Thanks for all of the quick reponses, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question isn't very clear because you don't specify what is broken or where you're having issues.   From what I gather, however, you don't need an IF/ELSE.  Instead you could do something like ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Year],  
        CASE [Year] 
            WHEN DATENAME(Year, GETDATE()) THEN 9999
            ELSE [Year] END  AS GarbageSoDistinctWorks
FROM Assessment 
WHERE ProjectCode = @ProjectCode
ORDER BY
        CASE [Year] 
            WHEN DATENAME(Year, GETDATE()) THEN 9999
            ELSE [Year] END  DESC
```

FYI ... i added the case to the select list as a throw away column to avoid the error I assume you're getting.. There are other ways, like a derived table, but for now this should work..

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

HTH,
-eric

Answer (score 5):

You don't need conditional statements here at all:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT [Year]
        FROM    Assessment
        WHERE   projectCode = @projectCode
        ) q
ORDER BY
        CASE [Year] WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
        [Year]
```

will output the current year (if exists) first, the other later.

Comment: This errors ...  "Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." You need to either do the distinct as a derived table, or include the CASE as a throw away column in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code appears to do what you describe.  What problems are you having?

As a side note: You don't need the IF statement.  By using the `ORDER BY` from your first example (with the `CASE` statement), you will get the correct results for both scenarios.
- If "this year" is in your data, it comes first.  Everything else comes next in DESC order
- If "this year" isn't in your data, you just get everything else in DESC order